# GWT использование Thread на сервере

Tags: java, gwt

Создал проект на GWT на основе стандартного примера - работает, пытаюсь к коду сервера добавить Thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    };
```

Получаю:

> ноя 23, 2015 10:47:42 PM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log INFO:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext log: greetServlet: ERROR: The
>   serialization policy file
>   '/testthread1/B338285BB91CE8921A27FE6C3AE53FF0.gwt.rpc' was not found;
>   did you forget to include it in this deployment? ноя 23, 2015 10:47:42
>   PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log INFO:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext log: greetServlet: Downloaded
>   serialization policy from
>   http://localhost:9876/policies/B338285BB91CE8921A27FE6C3AE53FF0.gwt.rpc
>   ноя 23, 2015 10:47:44 PM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log SEVERE:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming
>   RPC call com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service
>   method 'public abstract java.lang.String
>   com.test.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception:
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")   at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)

Не могли бы пояснить, что это за файл политики сериализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppEngine не позволяет использовать обычные нити.

Но вы можете использовать [Modules AP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Background_threads) для старта фоновых задач.

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Introduction).

> For instance, an app cannot spawn **threads** in some ways, write data to
>   the local file system or make arbitrary network connections. An app
>   also cannot use JNI or other native code. The JVM can execute any Java
>   bytecode that operates within the sandbox restrictions.

Comment: Но ведь на сервере, по идее, обычный сервлет, который наследуется от RemoteServiceServlet, неужели AppEngine запрещает использовать в сервлете обычные нити? Может его как - то можно отключить(AppEngine)?

Comment: Судя по документации https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Introduction это не отключаемо